# What does the hyphen mean in chkconfig run level in an /etc/init.d script?

Tags: init-script, init.d, chkconfig

I just have a simple question but scouring the search engines I have not found any explanation of what the `-` (hyphen) in the `chkconfig` runlevel actually stands for within the init script file.

For example in `/etc/init.d/mysqld` the first few lines are like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# mysqld        This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
#               the MySQL subsystem (mysqld).
#
# chkconfig: - 64 36
```

If anyone could provide me a link explaining this that would be awesome.

Comment: Where do you see this hyphen? Is it in the output of a command? What command?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying.. I have updated my original question for more clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hyphen (`-`) found in an init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: - 24 73
```

means that the service should not be started in any run levels by default, only stopped.

It replaces a list of run levels (e.g. 345) as shown below:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: 345 24 73
```

Therefore if you use:

```
chkconfig --add <script>
```

then no start links will be created in any of the `init` directories.

```
$ ll rc*.d/*script*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Apr 24  2014 rc0.d/K73script -> ../init.d/script
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Apr 24  2014 rc1.d/K73script -> ../init.d/script
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Apr 24  2014 rc2.d/K73script -> ../init.d/script
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Apr 24  2014 rc3.d/K73script -> ../init.d/script
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Apr 24  2014 rc4.d/K73script -> ../init.d/script
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Apr 24  2014 rc5.d/K73script -> ../init.d/script
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Apr 24  2014 rc6.d/K73script -> ../init.d/script
```

Notice only the `Kill` scripts links exist (`K73script`).

**References:**

*A reference to this can be found on [softpanorama.org](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Reference/chkconfig.shtml):*

> The first line tells chkconfig what runlevels the service should be started in by default, as well as the start and stop priority levels. If the service should not, by default, be started in any runlevels, a - should be used in place of the runlevels list.

Comment: Where is this documented? Could you give a source? I'm not saying it's wrong, just that your answer would be better if you could quote an official source for the information.

Comment: @terdon I would have done had I been able to find one! Finally, found and added.. :o)

Comment: Thanks. Dammit, this should be documented in a man page somewhere but I can't find it either.